# How Did I get the Yearling Badge Twice?

Tags: support

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Two criteria, neither possible to do more than once. Perhaps this description needs to be reworded.

Amusingly, both awards occurred the same week. I assume that relates to my getting a lot of upvotes on a [single answer](https://superuser.com/questions/472099/can-admins-monitor-my-activity-locally-even-when-i-use-a-vpn/472106#472106).

Comment: Just add *another* before each of the criteria, and you're good: *Active member for another year, earning at least another 200 reputation.*

Answer (score 6):

It's worded a little weird but basically every year that you earn at least 200 rep and stay active, you get the yearling badge.

Comment: The second sentence should be "This badge is awarded again for each combination of additional one year membership and 200 reputation."